# Can't get sound to work on new 14.04 install

Tags: sound

I checked `alsamixer` and it seems like it recognizes the device, but can't send sound to it. Also, my sound settings display no output, not even the dummy output. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: @user1914152 Try restarting your computer.

Comment: Full image: http://i.imgur.com/sLNwkfl.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your main soundcard is the 2nd one (the first is HDMI soundcard, attached to HDMI screen plug) .

So , in Alsamixer, press F6 , select 2nd soundcard : you will see more faders .Then  set volumes and unmute   faders (using arrow keys and "m" key to unmute. )

You can also install and run pavucontrol (Pulseaudio volume control) to access the 2nd sound card in the "output device" tab (click green button near it to make it default)